# Gridview ASP.NET lock first columns and first rows

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I need to freeze the columns 0, 1 at the same time I want the rows (NOT HEADER, HEADER is hidden) 0, 1, 2 frozen as well when the user scrolls up and down and also scrolls left to right these columns and rows will be statics in there, I tried some jQuery code but it did not work, I found this CSS example in a Stack Overflow question I took it for my project. So far I'm only working with the columns to get this done ASAP, however I will need as I said before the rows locked as well.

I have a gridview ASP.NET C# inside of an HTML table, in the event "load page" the grid gets filled with a datatable information. this Datable gets info from a SQL database.

I'm applying CSS on the grid when the events fire, all these work fine!

To give you an idea how the grid looks like, here your are an example:

[image]

You can't see the horizontal scroll bar because the amount of years the user chose, but this can change based on his selection.

This is the CSS I used lately:

```
    .pinned
{
    position:fixed; 
    background-color: #FFFFFF; 
    z-index: 100;


}
.scrolled
{
    position: relative;
    left: 150px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 50px; 
}
.col1
{
    left: 0px;
    width: 50px;
}
.col2

{
    left: 50px;  
    width: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
      <div style="overflow:scroll; height: 400px; width: 911px; margin:auto;">
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" GridLines="Vertical" OnRowCreated="COl" OnRowDataBound="ROWCSS" ShowHeader="false"> 

 </asp:GridView> 
</div>
```

This the C# code, when the rowcreated event fires: then I colspan the headers (first 3 rows -0,1,2-)

When the rowdatabound fires: then I apply the CSS font and background color:

```
        protected void ROWCSS(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = e.Row.Cells.Count;
        int index = e.Row.RowIndex;



        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

 //THIS IS THE FOR, THAT LOCKS THE COLUMN 0 and 1 ************

            for (int j = 0; j <= (i - 1); j++)
            {

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "pinned col1";
                }
                else if (j == 1)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "pinned col2";
                }

                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "scrolled";
                }

            }

 //********************************


            if (index == 3 || index == 32 || index == 46 || index == 50)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    //Si la columna es la 0 o la 1, entonces aplicar formato izquierdo
                    if (j == 0 || j == 1)
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "naranjaCSSLEFT";
                    }
                    //En caso contrario, formato derecho
                    else
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "naranjaCSSRIGHT";
                    }

                }
            }

            else if (index == 4 || index == 15 || index == 29 || index == 33 || index == 41)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    //Si la columna es la 0 o la 1, entonces aplicar formato izquierdo
                    if (j == 0 || j == 1)
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "azulCSSLEFT";
                    }
                    //En caso contrario, formato derecho
                    else
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "azulCSSRIGHT";
                    }

                }
            }

            else if (!(index == 0 || index == 1 || index == 2))
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    //Si la columna es la 0 o la 1, entonces aplicar formato izquierdo
                    if (j == 0 || j == 1)
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "negroCSSLEFT";
                    }
                    //En caso contrario, formato derecho
                    else
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "negroCSSRIGHT";
                    }

                }
            }



        }
    }
```

Finally this is some of the CSS I used to color fonts and background (not sure if this is necessary to provide):

```
                    .naranjaCSSLEFT
            {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#C65911;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align:left;
            font-family:tahoma;
            }
            .naranjaCSSRIGHT
            {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#C65911;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align:right;
            font-family:tahoma;
            }

            .azulCSSLEFT
            {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#2F75B5;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align:left;
            font-family:tahoma;
            }
            .azulCSSRIGHT
            {
            font-weight:bold;
            color:#2F75B5;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align:right;
            font-family:tahoma;
            }
            .negroCSSLEFT
            {
            font-weight:normal;
            color:#000000;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align:left;
            font-family:tahoma;
            }
            .negroCSSRIGHT
            {
            font-weight:normal ;
            color:#000000;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align:right;
            font-family:tahoma;

            }

            .FILACSS
            {
            font-weight:bold ;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align:center;
            font-family:tahoma;
            background:#2F75B5;
            border:hidden;
            }
```

If you are wondering what am I getting after applying this is this:

[image: After css effects]

It looks: screwed up! the 3 first rows... don't know what happened. The colspan is applied in a different event.

if you wonder what the colspan Rowcreated event is, is this:

```
        protected void COl(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
        int i = e.Row.Cells.Count;

        if (i == 4)
        {

            if (index == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    //e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "GVFixedHeader";
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }
                // e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "ACUMULADO DE ENERO - " + NomMes;

                e.Row.Cells[2].ColumnSpan = 2;
                e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(3);
            }

            if (index == 1)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

            }

            if (index == 2)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

            }



        }
        if (i == 8)
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    //e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";

                }

                //*******************************
                //e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "ACUMULADO DE ENERO - " + NomMes;
                e.Row.Cells[2].ColumnSpan = 6;

                for (int b = 7; b >= 3; b--)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(b);
                }


            }

            if (index == 1)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    //e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

                //******************************
                for (int b = 2; b <= 6; b++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[b].ColumnSpan = 2;
                    b++;
                }

                for (int b = 7; b >= 3; b--)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(b);
                    b--;
                }


            }

            if (index == 2)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    //e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

            }
        }
        if (i == 10)
        {

            if (index == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

                //*******************************
                //e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "ACUMULADO DE ENERO - " + NomMes;
                e.Row.Cells[2].ColumnSpan = 8;

                for (int b = 9; b >= 3; b--)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(b);
                }


            }

            if (index == 1)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

                //******************************
                for (int b = 2; b <= 8; b++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[b].ColumnSpan = 2;
                    b++;
                }

                for (int b = 9; b >= 3; b--)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(b);
                    b--;
                }


            }

            if (index == 2)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

            }

        }

        if (i == 12)
        {
            if (index == 0)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

                //*******************************
                //e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "ACUMULADO DE ENERO - " + NomMes;
                e.Row.Cells[2].ColumnSpan = 10;

                for (int b = 11; b >= 3; b--)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(b);
                }


            }

            if (index == 1)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

                //******************************
                for (int b = 2; b <= 10; b++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[b].ColumnSpan = 2;
                    b++;
                }

                for (int b = 11; b >= 3; b--)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(b);
                    b--;
                }


            }

            if (index == 2)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= (i - 1); j++)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "FILACSS";
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The columns are not getting frozen yet.

Answer (score 0):

I kept working on this last night and I found a solution for columns 0 and 1, nevertheless I'm still missing to freeze the first rows (0, 1, 2). This example I worked freezes the header but as I said previously I will hide header.

This is the new code I'm applying:

HTML:

```
                       <div>
                   <asp:GridView ID="cphMain_cphMain_cphMain_GridView2" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="true" GridLines="None" 
                       OnRowCreated="COl"   OnRowDataBound="ROWCSS">  
                   <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />

                </asp:GridView>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#cphMain_cphMain_cphMain_GridView2').gridviewScroll({
                            width: 930,
                            height: 400,
                            freezesize: 2
                        });
                    });
                 </script>
               </div>
```

In the "head" section I placed these scripts addresses:

HTML :

```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="JQuery/GridViewHeader.js"></script>
```

To provide the grid with CSS format I'm using the same Events I mentioned above, except the CSS extentions: Pinned, col1, col2, scrolled.

This is not longer used:

```
 //THIS IS THE FOR, THAT LOCKS THE COLUMN 0 and 1 ************

        for (int j = 0; j <= (i - 1); j++)
        {

            if (j == 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "pinned col1";
            }
            else if (j == 1)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "pinned col2";
            }

            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[j].CssClass = "scrolled";
            }

        }

//********************************
```

If you question what code is inside of:

```
<script src="JQuery/GridViewHeader.js"></script>
```

you can check that out in here (to be honest I can't read this I just found it and copied pasted):

http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js?20130319

I took the example from:

http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx